# Switch off Webpack's lazy loading globally, without magic comments

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there any way to switch off Webpack's lazy loading in one centralized place? Like with console switch or an option in `webpack.config.js` file?

I'm using "magic comments" `/* webpackMode: "eager" */` everywhere where I can, but if another second level module calls for third level module which lacks "magic comment" during its import.

As result I have one big bundle and several small chunks aside, while I would prefer them to be part of bigger bundle as the rest.

Unfortunately, I cannot walk all source tree and set `/* webpackMode: "eager" */`, since there are plenty of npm libraries there...

Is there any way how to solve that problem once and for all?

P.S. Webpack's version used is `4.30.0`.

At the moment there is an ongoing discussion on either `webpackMode: "eager"` should be default option for [Webpack 5](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8644). But no particular position is developed, as I can tell.

Comment: What Webpack version are you using?

Comment: @tomericco the latest one at the moment `4.30.0`. Will update question with this information too.

Comment: Why does your dependencies are being lazy loaded by default? I don't understand how you got to this situation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found answer to this question — standard Webpack's [LimitChunkCountPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/).

It could be used from `webpack.config.js` and also its settings could be overwritten from command line.

It worked for me without any additional efforts on `Webpack 4.30.0`. Here is the section that should be added to configuration file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1
    })
  ]
};
```

When merging this code with your configuration is important not to forget to import `webpack` (line #1).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to configure webpack's magic comments globally, in this case for `webpackMode`, you can use [`magic-comments-loader`](https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments-loader).

This will add `/* webpackMode: "eager" */` to all of your dynamic imports during a build.

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'magic-comments-loader',
        options: {
          webpackMode: 'eager'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This will only parse dynamic import expressions in your source code, not from `node_modules`.